# Video entry sender has only one signal line for Microphone + Speaker

Tags: audio, output, input, line

I am planning on connecting an off-the-shelf door camera (audio/video sender) to my project.

I've posted an extract from their manual here

[image]

The video output is composite which I can support, but only one audio signal is provided by the door camera. I expected two; output from the mic and an input for the speaker. My project has two signals - line in and line out.

How would I connect a single audio line like this to my line in/line out?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is it operates just like a telephone with both audio signals going down the same wire.  A pulsed offset voltage will trigger the door mechanism in the same sort of way as the telephone bell is operated (hence the way the door solenoid buzzes when activated).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. So as long as I don't supply the offset voltage I need not worry about the door release. How would I link this single signal to my two signals though?

Comment: If I am right, and it is a telephone-like signal, then this page should help you understand it more: http://www.epanorama.net/circuits/teleinterface.html  There are example circuits there of how to separate the two signals.

Answer (score 1):

It's unusual to see bidirectional audio on a unit like this because it's usually more trouble than it's worth for the sake of saving one wire. That said, there does only seem to be a single audio connection.

It's hard to be definitive without seeing the schematics but these are my thoughts. Assuming your door-entry system isn't using digital audio (highly unlikely), the 4-wire (speaker + mic) to 2-wire convertion will be done with a "two-wire hybrid" circuit which is usually implemented with a pair of op-amps (I can post an example schematic if you're interested). These circuits rely on a controlled impedance to prevent transmitted audio being returned to the sender. Having said that, it is actually desirable in a telephone system to be able to hear your own voice in the earpiece (known historically as [sidetone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidetone)), so some amount of "reflected" audio is beneficial.

However, connecting any external circuit to this will disturb the controlled impedance which *could* result in excessive sidetone which *might* cause acoustic feedback at the entrance panel (although there might be some automatic gain control in the panel to mitigate this). This will be less of an issue if you want to replace the handset with your circuit rather than add to it but you will need to know the correct line impedance.

Another problem you might face is echoes. Some years ago I was involved in  interfacing a city-wide two-wire door-entry system to the internet (the customer had been sold this functionality without consulting the engineers). The delays introduced by the digital channel meant that the audio feedback was delayed by about a second and the resultant echoes took a lot of time (and money) to cure!

Please excuse the "coulds" and "mights" but as I said, it's hard to be definitive without access to the circuit schematics.